# skip to next line of file ignoring content

Tags: c

hi so i have a program where if there is an @ at the begining of the first line of the text file it needs to be ignored, how do you jump to the next line of file? ignoring all that there is after the @?
for example:

```
@1234
5
```

I want to print 5 and the rest to be ignored.

I only managed to skip the `@` if there is nothing behind it

```
while (a == '@' || a == '\r'|| a == '\n') {            
    fscanf(inp, "%c", &a);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
while (a == '@' || a == '\r'|| a == '\n') {            
    fscanf(inp,"%c",&a);            
}
```

Try (pseudo code):

```
If FirstChar == '@'
  Loop/scan until '\n'

On nextline here
```

If you want to use `fscanf()`.

If better performance is needed, work on buffers directly.

Comment: @chqrlie - Yes, was tinking the same while typing it actually - I'll remove it. Memory mapping works on Windows too with CreateFileMapping().

Answer (score 0):

As for your previous question, if your want to ignore comment lines with an initial `@`, it is **highly** recommended to read the file line by line with `fgets()` and to handle non comment lines directly while ignoring comment lines.

It is actually non trivial to do it with `fscanf` because depending on your format lines, the linefeed may or may not have been consumed.

If you are at the start of a line and want to read the next char while ignoring the comment lines, do this:

```
int c;  // Must be int to accommodate for EOF.

while ((c = getc(inp)) == '@') {
    while ((c = getc(inp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
}

// Here c contains the first char from a non comment line or EOF.
```